# Перезапись XML и пуш его на сервер

Tags: php, xml, хеширование

Имеется такой xml код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request version="1.0">
  <merchant>
    <id>110012</id>
    <signature></signature>
  </merchant>
  <data>
    <oper>cmt</oper>
    <wait>1</wait>
    <test>1</test>
    <payment id="">
      <prop name="year" value="2016" />
      <prop name="month" value="03" />
    </payment>
  </data>
</request>
```

Это пуш запрос на Приват24, нужно захэшировать все что между тегами `<data>`
и перезаписать файл, чтоб в `<signature>` был этот хэш, например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request version="1.0">
  <merchant>
    <id>110012</id>
    <signature>fQcw9aL88zS8lu7hv0261DDa48npUB0M</signature>
  </merchant>
  <data>
    <oper>cmt</oper>
    <wait>1</wait>
    <test>1</test>
    <payment id="">
      <prop name="year" value="2016" />
      <prop name="month" value="03" />
    </payment>
  </data>
</request>
```

хэшируем это дело в `sha1(md5())` прошу решение, а то уже перепробовал кучу методов, а приват все также отвечает, что `<signature>` сгенерирован не правильно, спасибо :)

Как делалось :

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Httpful\Request;

$id = 110012;
$password = "fQcw9aL88zS8lu7hv0261DDa48npUB0M";
$uri = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/rest_yur";

$data = 
<<<EOD
    <oper>cmt</oper>
    <wait>1</wait>
    <test>1</test>
    <payment>
        <prop name="year" value="2016" />
        <prop name="month" value="04" />
    </payment>
EOD;

$sign = sha1(md5($data.$password));
$requestBody = 
<<<EOD
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <request version="1.0">
        <merchant>
            <id>$id</id>
            <signature>$sign</signature>
        </merchant>
        <data>$data</data>
    </request>
EOD;

$responce = \Httpful\Request::post($uri)
                        ->body($requestBody)
                        ->sendsXml()
                        ->send();

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($responce);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Документация которую предлагает приват 
https://api.privatbank.ua/rest-yur.html

Comment: что такое ` все что между тегами`. и покажите код, который не работает

Comment: Какое решение вы просите - `sha1(md5($val1 . $val2 . $val3))`?

Comment: @splash58 Добавил код, в ответ приват пишет : <error>Error parsing XML: not well-formed</error>

Comment: Ну, для начала, провалидируйте ваш результирующий xml и посмотрите что не так

Comment: @Чад дело в том, что сам xml правильный, не правильно я как то хэширую, по всей видимости, данные, вот как это грамотно сделать, я понятие не имею :С

Comment: Ну так дата то соответсвует запосу то? в вашем примере они разные. Вообще, пользуйтесь сбером :-D

Comment: Кодировка то у Вас utf-8?

Comment: @Чад вот с кодировкой не уверен, можете пожалуйста подсказать как ее поставить?

Comment: @Чад все, запрос отправляется нормально, но теперь ошибка invali ip :C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос: Не правильно создал форму XML